# How can i get permission to copy files from one folder to another?

Tags: permissions, command, cp, file-copy

So i was trying to copy some files from one folder to another using the `cp` command, but when tried it gave me this error:

```
debian@OCR-1:/mnt/rootfs/boot$ ls
MLO             omap3-overo-storm-arbor43c.dtb  uEnv.txt  zImage-3.18-20150915
initrd-ubi.img  u-boot.img   zImage
debian@OCR-1:~$ cp /mnt/rootfs/boot/MLO /var/log/MLO
cp: can't create '/var/log/MLO': Permission denied
```

so then i tried to execute the same command with `sudo` but it didn't work either:

```
debian@OCR-1:~$ sudo cp /mnt/rootfs/boot/MLO /var/log/MLO
-bash: sudo: command not found
```

After i tried to see the permissions of each folder:

```
debian@OCR-1:/var$ ls -l
total 5
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root 4096 May 16  2018 archive
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root    0 Jan  1 00:00 lib
drwxrwxr-x  2 root root    0 Jan  1 00:56 lock
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root 1024 Jan  1 00:00 log
drwxrwxr-x  4 root root    0 Jan  1 00:01 run
drwxrwxr-x  3 root root    0 Jan  1 00:00 spool
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root    0 Jan  1 00:00 www

debian@OCR-1:/mnt/rootfs/boot$ ls -l
total 11160
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   59148 Jan 24  2014 MLO
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1220219 Jan  1 00:16 initrd-ubi.img
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   69463 Jan 24  2014 omap3-overo-storm-arbor43c.dtb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  470632 Jan 24  2014 u-boot.img
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    2038 Jan  1 00:16 uEnv.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4798000 Jan  1 00:20 zImage
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4798000 Jan 24  2014 zImage-3.18-20150915
```

but then i don't know what to do next because i don't know how to understand the data. Can somebody help me solve this problem?

[EDIT]

So i tried to see if i had root access, but is shows me this:

```
debian@OCR-1:~$ id
uid=1000(debian) gid=1002(debian) groups=4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),25(floppy),29(audio),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),100(users),106(netdev),108(i2c),1000(admin),1001(spi),1002(debian)
debian@OCR-1:~$ whoami
debian
debian@OCR-1:~$ su -
su: must be suid to work properly
```

And then i tried to install `sudo`, but i can't:

```
debian@OCR-1:~$ apt update && apt install -y sudo
-bash: apt: command not found
```

Comment: What is the result of `ls -ld /var/log/MLO`?

Comment: Do you have root access?

Comment: @RomeoNinov that was the name of the copy of the file that was supposed to be created by the cp command, so it doen't exist

Comment: @iLuvLogix how can i know if i have root access?

Comment: try `su -`, and when asked for a password, type in pwd for root.. If you don't have root access and sudo isn't installed or you aren't a member of the sudo group, speak to your sys-administrator ;)

Comment: @iLuvLogix i updated my question and you can see that su - doesn't work, any idea?

Comment: @JoãoSousa, what is your distribution?

Comment: @RomeoNinov `debian@OCR-1:~$ uname -a
Linux OCR-1 3.18.20-RCS480-ga0327eb-dirty #17 SMP Tue Sep 15 16:41:12 PDT 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux`

Comment: What you need to do is talk to whoever is the sysadm on this machine to give you the desirded permissions. Have you setup this machine (physically or via VM/container etc..)?

Comment: @iLuvLogix it wasn't me who setup this machine, i am only trying to copy the files inside of it. This is a Debian GNU/Linux that was put inside of a Gumstix Overo, and i wanted to recover the files from that Gumstix Overo.

Comment: From support: _'Enter the username root at the prompt and press Enter to login. There is no password on newly-flashed images.'_ If it isn't a new image, I dont see a way unless you have the original root-password from whoever setup this machine. You could try get/read the image somehow from the hw of your gumstick in order to replicate it in dozens of containers and bruteforce the password via some dict-files and automated scripts, but that requires a bit more than your average embedded skills..

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to use `sudo` on debian, you first need to install and configure it.

---

##### install `sudo`:

First you need to login to your root account.

Then run the following to install the `sudo` package:

```
apt update && apt install -y sudo
```

---

##### configure `sudo`:

If the installation completes without errors, you can configure `sudo` to allow your user to escalate privileges.
Debian usually is by default configured to allow users which are in the sudo group to run commands via sudo.
You can check that by, while still logged into the root account, running `visudo` and look for the following line:

```
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

If there is a `#` in front of `%sudo` remove it so that the line looks exactly as above. Be very careful to not mess up the file, as it could render your system unusable!

---

###### add your user to the sudo group:

If the line is present, you can add your normal user, in your case `debian` to the sudo group. You can do that with `usermod`:

```
usermod -aG sudo debian
```

Where `-aG` means "append to group"

```
-a, --append
           Add the user to the supplementary group(s). Use only with the -G option.

-G, --groups GROUP1[,GROUP2,...[,GROUPN]]]
           A list of supplementary groups which the user is also a member of. Each group is separated from the next by a comma, with no intervening whitespace. The groups are subject to the same
           restrictions as the group given with the -g option.

           If the user is currently a member of a group which is not listed, the user will be removed from the group. This behaviour can be changed via the -a option, which appends the user to the current
           supplementary group list.
```

Now logout of the root account and login to your debian user account.
You should now be able to run commands as root via `sudo`.

**Note:** that the directory `/var/log/` usually is only for automatically generated log files.

Comment: I can't install sudo, i updated my question, doesn't have apt command

Comment: @JoãoSousa It is expected that you don't have access to `apt` if you are not `root`.